# WordPress MySQL Database Recovery

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm moving files from one Windows server to another and only have access to the files, not the actual Windows environment.

I have a few WordPress sites, all of which use MySQL.

Inside my data folder, I see the following:

```
wordpress8\
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
ibdata1
```

I want to bring this wordpress8 database over to my new install of MySQL on the new server.

How do I do this? The WordPress folder has a bunch of .frm files and an .opt file.

My new install of MySQL already has an ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 - so i don't think I want to overwrite these.

Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: _Don't_ attempt to copy a MySQL database by copying files from its data directory. And note that your database might not even live on the machine you can access. Your best bet is to use the same database credentials that WordPress uses to [dump the database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html), then [load it on your other server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Can I do that without having a UI to the database? All i have is recovery mode to the old server. I know all the details that Wordpress used for the database.

Comment: It depends how everything is configured; the database is probably only accessible from certain places. Another option would be to [export from WordPress](https://en.support.wordpress.com/export/) and import on the new server.

Comment: Sadly old server doesn't boot now so no access to WordPress or MySQL Command line.

Comment: Could I take the ibdata file and the wordpress8 data folder and install MySQL on my own machine, create a database with the same name and user etc. then replace the created folder and ibdata with my backup ones then export to sql ready for import?

Comment: Then your best bet will be to restore from your most recent database backup. You have one, right? (You can _try_ to recover the database from files in the data directory, but there's no guarantee they're even consistent. I would _strongly_ advise finding a way to ask MySQL for the data politely—using `mysqldump`, WordPress exporrt, etc.—if possible.)

Comment: Got it working - installed MySQL locally and verified the file sizes of all the MySQL files were the same as a base install. Then copied over the new data folder as well as the ibdata file. Had to create the user in the database as they didn't exist

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, but I don't think this is a generally applicable solution. For anybody else who tries this, make sure to use the same version of MySQL on the replacement server.